# Does the [live-mixing] refer to mixing in real time, e.g. DJing etc, or mixing for a live audience, e.g. FOH?

Tags: discussion, tags

I started to write a tag wiki that would have defined it as the *mixing for a live audience* variety.  Half way through, I realized that the tag itself is vague.

Also there is a [live](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/live) tag (40+ atm) that is used for everything from ... well... everything.

I'm not saying it's surprising to have such vagaries, just wanted to discuss them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging by the questions currently tagged live-mixing, it seems to mostly apply to mixing for a live audience.

There is also a DJ tag that should be used for questions specific to DJing.

There is also the possibility for some questions to be tagged with both.

Comment: Okay, tag should be fairly cleaned up now.